# Is it better to use classes or multi-dimensional arrays for the task given bellow?

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array, visual-c++

I am kind of new in c++. I was wondering should I do this using class/es or with multi-dimensional arrays? I really need some pointers on how to achieve these goals!

So, I have the following task:

Make a program that is used as an information system for the World competition in Athletics. The program should keep and modify information about athletes, as for each athlete -> ( number in the competition, name, discipline, the best result in his career, the best result for this year, number of participations in world competitions). There must be 5 different disciplines (200m Sprint, 4x400m, Throwing spear, high jump, triple jump). In each discipline, there will be 6 athletes.

A. Menu for using the functions in the program ( I have made most of it, I believe)

B. Adding athletes
     i. Add one athlete in each discipline.
     ii. Add a list of athletes, write number N and after it N athletes per discipline.

C. Show all athletes on the screen

D. Run a competition

i. Runs randomly for each athlete. The athlete can score no less than 20% of his best score for the year and no more than 10% of his best score for the career.

ii. There is a 5% chance for each athlete to do a fault-start.

E. Table of medals - athletes in each competition are grouped by countries in a new array(1st place-30p, scnd - 20p, etc, etc). The array is shown on screen in increasing order (also showing the name of country, points, list of athletes from this country, their scores during the competition)

F. Show some extra info:

i. Show on-screen athletes ordered by age

ii. Sow on-screen athletes ordered by name

iii. Show on-screen the athlete with the most participation in world competitions

iiii. Show on-screen the country with most athletes

G. The data in the program can be saved in a file between two runs of the program.

Comment: Related data should almost always be grouped into a structure (class), if that's what you're wondering. Then you can have an array (or vector) of instances of that structure. You might want to read some basic books or tutorials about object-oriented programming and *design* to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly fast response!

If i get you right, there should be a class grouping the related data. And maybe an array(or vector) in this class for each discipline :? 
I have ordered a book from Amazon more than 45 days ago and still waiting for it..

Comment: Yes that sounds good. Generally speaking, if you have something tangible (like an athlete) it should probably be a class.

Comment: Okay, imma get to reading/learning then! If you know any quality tutorials/read materials, I would be even more grateful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... should i do this using class/es or with multi-dimensional arrays?

Nearly any C++ program with a complexicity level just a little above "hello world" will use classes to gather related information into a single object.

In your case an obvious class would be a class representing an athlete. Like:

```
class athlete
{
    string name;
    uint32_t competition_number;
    ...
    ...
};
```

Then you migth want another class holding all athletes using a vector. Something like:

```
class participants
{
    vector<athlete> participants;
    ...
    ...
}
```

If you start out with those two classes, you'll be able solve many parts of the homework.

Similar for the competition, it will probably make sense with some class (perhaps templated) to represent a competion. One member variable of such a class could be a vector of participants of that specific competion. A member function could be `run()`.

With respect to arrays: Arrays are in many cases replaced by vectors in C++. In case you need a multi-dimention container, multi-dimentional vectors can be created like:

```
vector<vector<int> x;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have another issue tho. How am I supposed to add members to the class based on the user input ? As in the task description, it is said that the user should be able to add athletes. I read about maps but I am in the first semester of my uni and I am pretty sure we are not supposed to go that deep with this semester course work. Any ideas?

Comment: @StefanVelikov If you have a simple vector of int, you can add integers to the vector using vector.push_back(123). If you have a vector of your own class it is just the same, i.e use push_back

Comment: @StefanVelikov You can also use emplace_back - see https://ideone.com/uOho5H for a simple example